# Gatsby npm run build fails

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project that **WORKS WELL** in develop mode, but when I try to run build, I get context related errors from Webpack

Other times, I don't get the context related error, but I get a theme related error (I'm using styled components), I defined a global theme and webpack doesn't recognize the values. For instance, when I do

```
    @media ${({ theme }) => theme.currentDevice.laptop} {
        margin-top: 10em;
    }
```

Webpack says theme.currentDevice is undefined, so 'laptop' can't be recognized

```
WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'laptop')
```

But it all works well in develop

It is kind of having problems with global things, I don't know...

I sense that the problem is elsewhere, but Webpack throws those errors

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share how you set the global theme or what are those "context-related errors"?

Comment: I'll try to create a sandbox with the site, I'll let you know when

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

The problem was that I was using the CommonJS syntax in gatsby-ssr.js and the ES6 syntax in gatsby-browser.js, it seems that it is a bad thing